# Ruby private method

Tags: ruby, methods, private

I  am studying ruby and somehow, I define some methods as private and I get the error: "undefined method private for class ...". I Post tmy code below. Any help or suggestion will do! Thank you :)

Code:

```
class Bot
attr_reader :name

def initialize(options)
    @name = options[:name] || "Unnamed Bot"
    begin
        @data =  YAML.load(File.read(options[:data_file]))
    rescue
        raise "Could not load bot data"
    end

    private

        def random_response(key)
            random_index = rand(@data[:responses][key].length)
            @data[:responses][key][random_index].gsub(/\[name\]/, @name)
        end

        def greeting
            random_response :greeting
        end

        def farewell
            radnom_response :farewell
        end

        def response_to(input)
            prepared_input = preprocess(input).downcase
        end

        def preprocess(input)
            perform_substitutions input
        end
end 
end
```

Error:

Comment: All of your methods are defined inside your constructor in this code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While indenting isn't critical in Ruby, keeping track of it is very useful when looking for problems in your code, so make it a habit to do it consistently. Use two-spaces per indent and set your tabstops to 2.

Here's your code indented consistently:

```
class Bot
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(options)
    @name = options[:name] || "Unnamed Bot"
    begin
      @data =  YAML.load(File.read(options[:data_file]))
    rescue
      raise "Could not load bot data"
    end

    private

    def random_response(key)
      random_index = rand(@data[:responses][key].length)
      @data[:responses][key][random_index].gsub(/\[name\]/, @name)
    end

    def greeting
      random_response :greeting
    end

    def farewell
      radnom_response :farewell
    end

    def response_to(input)
      prepared_input = preprocess(input).downcase
    end

    def preprocess(input)
      perform_substitutions input
    end
  end
```

Notice that you're missed `end` for your `def initialize` method due to the closing `end` to your `rescue` block. Also, that your methods are embedded inside `initialize` and how that stands out?

Answer (score 4):

Your private methods are part of the class constructor (the `initialize` method); they should be defined outside of other methods.